# zsh displaying the exported function

Tags: macos, unix, zsh

Created a simple function and exported it in `.zshenv`. When I started the terminal it outputs the function on the console. How can I stop doing this?

.zshenv

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Users/guru/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-1.8.0_322/Contents/Home
export export ENV=dev
function myfun() {
    echo "Hello!"
}
export -f myfun
```

zsh -x

```
guru@Gurunaths-MacBook-Pro ~ % zsh -x
+/Users/guru/.zshenv:1> export JAVA_HOME=/Users/guru/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-1.8.0_322/Contents/Home
+/Users/guru/.zshenv:2> export export ENV=dev
+/Users/guru/.zshenv:9> export -f myfun
myfun () {
    echo "Hello!"
}
+/etc/zshrc:7> [[+/etc/zshrc:7> locale LC_CTYPE
+/etc/zshrc:7> [[ UTF-8 == UTF-8 ]]
+/etc/zshrc:8> setopt COMBINING_CHARS
+/etc/zshrc:12> disable log
+/etc/zshrc:15> HISTFILE=/Users/guru/.zsh_history 
+/etc/zshrc:16> HISTSIZE=2000 
+/etc/zshrc:17> SAVEHIST=1000 
+/etc/zshrc:20> setopt BEEP
+/etc/zshrc:24> [[ -r /Users/guru/.zkbd/xterm-256color-apple ]]
```

Comment: There's something wrong in your .zshenv (or maybe another startup file); without knowing what's in them, it's impossible to do more than guess at the problem. What do you mean by "export"? In zsh, that's really only applicable to variables, not functions. Also, please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); post the text itself (in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361), so it displays accurately).

Comment: One of your startup files must contain code which displays the function, and you need to find out, where it happens. For a first test, I would cretate a subshell with `zsh -lx` and analyze the output.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't know that functions are not allowed to export in zsh. I thought it will work as it works in bash.
Also, formatted the code as per your suggestions.

Comment: @user1934428 TBH, I don't understand if there are any issues in output of zsh -x

Comment: Well, you look through the output until you see the undesired output. Just before this, the trace displays the statement which was the culprit for that printing.

Comment: The `export -f` in your code is weird. Is this a new feature of zsh? Which zsh version are you using? Actually, now when I'm thinking of it: I am not aware that zsh would have exported functions at all, so I guess it's a new feature. In my zsh, I get the error message _export: invalid option(s)_. This makes me also wonder whether you are really running `zsh`. What does a `echo $ZSH_VERSION` say?

Comment: @user1934428 $ZSH_VERSION is 5.8.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248798/discussion-between-ramis-and-user1934428).

Answer (score 0):

I did this as a workaround to stop displaying the function content. The `%` is my shell prompt.

```
% tail -2 .zshenv
myfun() { echo "Hello!" }
export -f myfun > /dev/null
% zsh
% myfun
Hello!
```

Get to know only today, zsh only exports variables but not functions. But, not sure why my version of zsh does it! Searched why its not allowed, and came across some good stuff [Shellshock/bashdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))

Comment: This makes me wonder how you can know that your zsh exports functions. Nothing in the code you posted, would verify this. What surprises me more, is that you did not get any error message from `export -f`, and if I were you, THIS is for sure something I would research further. If a command fails to produce error output when invoked incorrectly, this always smells like something is dangerously wrong in your environment.